# Checking if any date between date range was within a specific year

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I am racking my brain on this one. I have a list of campaigns and their associated start and end dates. I'm trying to write a query to list the campaigns where at least one day between the start and end date was in 2017. My original thought was just use datepart():

```
datepart(yyyy,StartDt = 2017) OR datepart(yyyy,EndDt = 2017)
```

But that wont pick up a campaign that started before 2017 and ended after 2017, like start date 1/1/2016 and end date 1/1/2018.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably the easiest way to do this is like this (it's something I use when having to do temporal table queries):

```
WHERE CampaignStartDate < '2018-01-01'
AND CampaignEndDate >= '2017-01-01'
```

This guarantees that your campaign start and end dates had at least some overlap with the 2017 year.  It's a good way of testing if two time ranges overlap at all.

Comment: @Veljko89 Read it again carefully.  It compares the start date to the end of 2017 and the campaign end date to the beginning of 2017.  Your example still passes this where clause.  (This is the same logic SQLServer 2016 uses for some of it's temporal table clauses.  Very similar to `FOR system_time FROM x TO y`.)

Comment: Wow, I feel dumb. Thanks.

Comment: An added benefit of not using `DatePart()` on the columns is that the query engine can use index seeks to improve performance. PSA regarding literal dates: [ISO date format](https://xkcd.com/1179/).